# Q: How to perform an ADD operation to a specific Array Index on DynamoDB using Expression Builder

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

It's possible to perform a ADD operation to a specific Array Index using Expression Builder?

For example:

```
Item: {
  SomeId string
  Answers []int {0, 0, 0, 0}
}

exprBuilder := expression.Add(expression.Name(??), expression.Value(1))
```

How can I access the Answers[1] for example using the expression builder?

I could do something like this:

```
Item: {
  SomeId string
  AnswerOne int
  AnswerTwo int
}

exprBuilder := expression.Add(expression.Name("AnswerOne"), expression.Value(1))
```

But this is kinda bad because I would be restricted to a specific amount previous estabilished.

Comment: Is `Anwers` is range key here ?. If yes, yes we access Answers by range key, then we can update.